# error 91 when running if activeworkbook.name = "inventariogen.xls" code is stored in personal macro workbook and is triggered when workbook_open

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "inventariogen.xls" Then 'brings error 91

'whatever I need it to do

end if
end sub
```

please help error 91 when running if activeworkbook.name = "inventariogen.xls"  code is stored in personal macro workbook and is triggered when workbook_open

Comment: I believe `ActiveWorkbook` is not being identified properly. The error implies the object is missing. In this instance the workbook is the object

Comment: @urdearboy hi, I've tried it both ways

Comment: Try this `If Lcase(ActiveWorkbook.Name) = "inventariogen.xls"`

Comment: Also ensure the extention is correct. you can chect that bu typing `?Lcase(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` in the immediate window

Comment: @SiddharthRout hi, still get error 91

Comment: What do you get when you type `?Lcase(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` in the Immediate Window? If you cannot see the immediate window, press CTRL + G in VBE

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I get inventariogen.xls

Comment: I wonder if the book is not actually active yet by the time the code runs. Can you try to add `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))` before your `If` statement? It doesnt sound like a name issue otherwise it would just skip your If and end sub. It is missing the actual object (workbook)

Comment: Ok try what I suggested [HERE](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?533489-RESOLVED-run-time-error-91-activeworkbook-name&p=3297387&viewfull=1#post3297387)

Comment: @undearboy tried it and still getting the error on the if statement

Comment: @SiddharthRout unhiding the personal wb helped with the error, but now the macro isn´t running

Comment: Please elaborate on `the macro isn´t running`

Comment: @SiddharthRout as in nothing happens, I verified and the workbook's name is correct and everything

Comment: see my first comment. did you try that? You may want to step through the code to see what exactly is happening?